# Adding a polygon mask causes flicker/ cutting

Tags: davinci-resolve

Whenever I add a polygon mask, it causes strange flickering/ cutting where it doesn't intersect with the polygon (as in picture).

It cutts it off at the top, when surely it should be displaying everything outside of the mask.[image]

Comment: What is your Transform node doing to the Text node? Could it be cropping it before it gets to the merge?  Is the Text node generating at the same aspect ratio as the background image?

Comment: Nope, it happens regardless of whether that transform node is there or not.